# how to get certain text from the html element by traversing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am working on tooltip in javascript.i have an HTML template. that template should be in the tooltip. For user reference i have a static text on that template. that text may be in div or span or table ,anything..
In javascript or jquery i need to get that text and replce with current tooltip value.
below is my code..

```
<div id="Template" style="display: none;">
    <div id="icon">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
    <div id="value">
        <div>
            <label>&nbsp;#tooltipText#</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    var k=$('#Template');
    if(template.childnodes. haveText(#tooltipText#)){
    need to replace the text with some value like 'Antartica'.
    }
</script>
```

that is I need to change that text **#tooltipText#** with some value using JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: `.text()` is what you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element that cointains '#tooltipText#' using `:contains`:

```
var placeholderParent = k.find(':contains(#tooltipText#)').last();
placeholderParent.html( placeholderParent.html().replace('#tooltipText#', 'Antarctica'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxw1j2nj/

But I think it's an overkill and you could simply replace the '#tooltipText#' in the whole template:

```
k.html( k.html().replace('#tooltipText#', 'Antarctica'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxw1j2nj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('#value').find('label').text('Antartica');
```

Comment: it may be in span or table.. but you suggestion is only find it in the label.

Comment: then find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('#value').find("label:contains('tooltipText')").text("Antartica");
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bj10m6tL/